# Binary search for IOI problem: Cave

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity, binary-search

## Question

http://www.ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi13/contest/day2/cave/cave.pdf

## Code

```
#include "cave.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int MAXN = 5001;
int status[MAXN] , door[MAXN] , guess[MAXN];

void exploreCave(int N){
  memset(door , -1 , sizeof(door));
  for(int n = 0 ; n < N ; n++){
    int r = tryCombination(status);
    int low = 0 , high = N - 1;
    while(low != high){
      bool changed = false;
      int a = low , b = (low + high) / 2;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
        if(i >= a && i <= b){
          if(door[i] != -1){
            guess[i] = status[i];
          }
          else {
            guess[i] = !status[i];
            changed = true;
          }
        }
        else guess[i] = status[i];
      }
      int K = r;
      if(changed) K = tryCombination(guess);
      if(r == n){
        if(K > n || K == -1)
          high = b;
        else low = b + 1;
      }
      else {
        if(K == n) high = b;
        else low = b + 1;
      }
    }
    door[low] = n;
    if(r == n) status[low] = !status[low];
  }
    answer(status , door);
}
```

## Issue

While this is a working and correct code, I runs at O(NlogN) time(I think).  Is there a possible way to further shorten the time complexity?  This code uses binary search.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you really lucked out with `memset(door , -1 , sizeof(door));`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `memset()` sets bytes one by one, but you have an array of a multi-byte value. In your case, this works because the binary representation of -1 for a `int` just happens to be the same as 4 consecutive -1 bytes (`char`).  You should just use `std::fill()`, and let the compiler figure out how to best fill the memory.

Comment: hmm i see, so my method is not the legit method, right?

Comment: "legit" is very circumstantial in C++. There are cases where what you did is the right thing to do (when you known exactly what you are doing and why you are doing it). The "recommended" way of filling an array with a value is with `std::fill`. Mind you, good code would also use `std::array<>` instead of raw arrays,  not use global variables, and a bunch of other details.

Comment: I see all my seniors who are teaching me do that, and they've did that for IOI and NOI

Comment: @Frank your comments could be wrapped up in a nice answer

Comment: Links rot over time.  You should summarize the task in your own words and put it here along with the link.

Comment: @XcoderX The thing about competitive programming is that you review it differently than usual. It's perfectly acceptable (and even preferable) to use `memset` if it's easier for you to remember in a competitive environment. You are correct that your code runs in `O(N log N)`. As an exercise, convince yourself that the complexity is optimal. (Observe also that the stated limit is 70 000 ops, and `N log N` with `N = 5000` comes out to 61 439.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prefer Clear Naming over using namespace std**

Before I go into why

```
using namespace std;
```

is to be avoided, in the case of this program it is not needed since there is no use of any functions that derive from the std namespace in this code.

According to the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx):

> Namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries.

A collision is when 2 different functions have the same name, the same arguement types and a similar functionallity (this is why they have the same name). Someone developing software may want to override a function such as `std::cout`, `std::cin` or they may want to override the functionallity of a class such as std::vector or std::stack. Namespaces allow these constructs to be overriden.

The use of the programming statement:

```
using namespace std;
```

hides the fact that cin, cout, vector and stack are coming from the namespace std where cin, cout,
vector and stack are used in the code. This can cause confusion of where the code is actually
coming from.

As the software becomes more complex and uses more libraries this becomes a bigger problem.

For a more detailed discussion of why it is a bad idea to use `using namespace std;` see this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer) and [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

**Use Standard Libraries When Possible**

Instead of writing a binary search it might be better to use the one provided by the [standard template library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/). It saves time when writing code, and every effort has been made to make the standard library functions as efficient as possible, which means you won't generally have to optimize it.

To use the standard library binary search you would need to include the  algorithm header

```
#include <algorithm>
```

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**

The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

> Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:
>           `A class should have only one reason to change.`

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and subroutines well.

The `void exploreCave(int N)` function could be broken up into at least two functions. This code specifically seems to be a good candidate for a function.

```
    while (low != high) {
        bool changed = false;
        int a = low;
        int b = (low + high) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (i >= a && i <= b) {
                if (door[i] != -1) {
                    guess[i] = status[i];
                }
                else {
                    guess[i] = !status[i];
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
            else guess[i] = status[i];
        }
    }
```

The more separate functions there are the easier it is to understand or read the code. This also makes it easier for any programmer to maintain or debug the code.

**Use Meaningful Variable Names**

The variables r, K and N do not help the reader understand the code. It's not clear at all what the variables r and K are. N is defined only if one reads the problem description, which is not currently included in the question. There are some good variable names such as guess, status, and changed although it might be better to make the array names plural. Variable naming should be consistent. The function name `exploreCave` is quite clear as well. Using `i` and `j` is quite common and understandable, but what is `r` and `K`? A second question is why is `K` needed since `r` does not change between it's assignment and usage?

**Use One Statement to Declare and Initialize a Single Variable**

When the arrays `status`, `door` and `guess` are declared as when the variables `low` and `high` are declared and initialized it is done so on a single line. This makes the code harder to read and maintain. I initially missed the declaration and initialization of `high`. To make the code more readable and easier to maintain declare variables on separate lines in new statements.

```
    int low = 0;
    int high = N - 1;
```

is much easier to read and maintain than

```
    int low = 0 , high = N - 1;
```

You may not be the person maintaining the code, and even if you are it may be multiple years between initially writing the code and modifying it. It is important to make the code as readable as possible.

Comment: I can't agree with the bulk of this answer. The very nature of a solution to a competitive programming problem is that it is not intended to be maintained; it is to be written once, then discarded. In that respect, it's not meaningful to make the majority of the recommendations. Furthermore, while the general advice to use the standard library is great, this problem uses a specialized binary search with side effects, so `std::binary_search` is useless here.